# UNITY Prevent 3D Text Render Trough All Object Without Shader

Tags: unity, 2d, 3d, graphics, text

im tired of those answer i found trough search engine that just keep saying " the trick is to modify the shader " without thinking because they want to gain reputation , in my case , i have **2 3D text** , one of them using **special font** and the other  one using **default font** , and **the shader to prevent the text render trough all object from http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=3DText is not working** and giving ***weird white square*** plus ***i don't want to change from default Arial font because i want to make them look different*** , i also **cannot use sprite** as background because i need to change their color trough script to give some effect , this is my picture showing my problem -- :

[image: Faded - By Alan Walker , have you played game such as Demonophobia ? or ib ? or Mad Father ?]

If the picture is not clear , go here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLqC9.png

The menu dropped is at Z = 100 while the background is at Z = 20 , as you see , the text is rendered while the other not ( such as the border , ect ).

And this is the picture when my special font without using the shader

[image: I set my hearth on fire ~]

If the picture is not clear , go here https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbrQ1.png

Now the picture of my special font using the shader

[image: Where are you now .... ~]

If the picture is not clear , go here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMAR2.png

Is there any possible way to prevent the text rendered without shader / change the background to sprite  ?

Im sorry if this already asked somewhere , i just cannot find it at search engine ( neither here ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ! i found out the answer myself , the way to do it is by creating material , make the material type ( or shader ) into sprite / default ! using that way i stil can change the color of the background  .

Before :

[image: - Faded By Alan Walker -]

After adding material :

[image: I set my hearth on fire ~]

Proof i still can change the color of the object that have the material in it :

[image]